# Does a neural network require binary inputs?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [working on a proj in neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450574/working-on-a-proj-in-neural-network)

Is it mandatory that neural network will only take binary values as an input?

Comment: It's a duplicate of an about to close question that he asked yesterday

Answer (score 6):

No. They're not even restricted to a binary output, unless you're using a step function for activation.